# Embedded Linux – mechanism for deploying firmware updates?

Tags: linux, embedded, patch, yocto

I am considering developing on the Yocto project for an embedded Linux project (an industrial application) and I have a few questions for those with experience with embedded Linux in general -- Yocto experience a bonus.  Just need to get an idea of what is being commonly done in firmware updates.

I have a few requirements, that being authentication, a secure communications protocol, some type of rollback if the update failed.  Also, if there is a way to gradually release the patch across the fleet of devices then that would also be interesting as I want to avoid bricked devices in the field.

How do you deploy updates/patches to field devices today – and how long did it take to develop it?  Are there any other considerations I am missing?

Answer (score 16):

Although you certainly can use rpm, deb, or ipk for your upgrades, my preferred way (at least for small to reasonably sized images) is to have two images stored on flash, and to only update complete rootfs images.

Today I would probably look at meta-swupdate if I were to start working with embedded Linux using OpenEmbedded / Yocto Project.

What I've been using for myself and multiple clients is something more like this:

- A container upgrade file which is a tarball consisting of another tarball (hereafter called the upgrade file), the md5sum of the upgrade file, and often a gpg-signature.
- An updater script stored in the running image. This script is responsible to unpack the outer container of the upgrade file, verify the correctness of the upgrade file using md5sum and often to verify a cryptographic signature (normally gpg based). If the update file passes these tests, the updater script looks for a upgrade script inside the update file, and executes this.
- The upgrade script inside the update file performs the actual upgrade, ie normally rewrite the non-running image, extracting and rewriting the kernel and if these steps are successful, instruct the bootloader to use the newly written kernel and image instead of the currently running system.

The benefit of having the script that performs the actual upgrade inside the upgrade file, is that you can do whatever you need in the future in a single step. I've made special upgrade images that upgrades the FW of attached modems, or that extracted some extra diagnostics information instead of performing an actual upgrade. This flexibility will payoff in the future.

To make the system even more reliable, the bootloader users a feature called bootcount, which could the number of boot attempts, and if this number gets above a threshold, eg 3, the bootloader chooses to boot the other image (as the image configured to be booted is considered to be faulty). This ensures that of the image is completely corrupt, the other, stored image will automatically be booted.

The main risk with this scheme is that you upgrade to an image, whose upgrade mechanism is broken. Normally, we also implement some kind of restoration mechanism in the bootloader, such that the bootloader can reflash a completely new system; though this rescue mechanism usually means that the data partition (used to store configurations, databases, etc) also will be erased. This is partly for security (not leaking info) and partly to ensure that after this rescue operation the system state will be completely known to us. (Which is a great benefit when this is performed by an inexperienced technician far away).

Comment: I am looking to use meta-swupdate on Edison, but this is the first time I will be using any update agent. Are there any steps that I can follow to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you do have enough flash storage, you can do the following. Make two identical partitions, one for the live system, the other for the update. Let the system pull the updated image over a secure method, and write it directly to the other partition. It can be as simple as plugging in a flash drive, with the USB socket behind a locked plate (physical security), or using ssh/scp with appropriate host and user keys. Swap the partitions with `sfdisk`, or edit the setting of your bootloader **only** if the image is downloaded and written correctly. If not, then nothing happens, the old firmware lives on, and you can retry later. If you need gradual releases, then let the clients select an image based on the last byte of their MAC address. All this can be implemented with a few simple shellscripts in a few hours. Or a few days with actually testing it :)

Answer (score 1):

@Anders answer is complete exaustive and very good. The only thing I can add as a suggestion to you is to think on some things:

- Has your application an internet connection/USB/SD card to store a
  complete new rootfs? Working with Linux embedded is not the like write a 128K firmware on a Cortex M3..
- Has your final user the capability to do the update work?
- Is your application installed in a accessible area remote controlled?

About the time you need to develop a complete/robust/stable solution is not a so simple question, but take notes that is a key point of an application that impact on the market feeling of your application. Especially in early days/month of first deploy where is usual to send updates to fix little/big youth bugs.

Comment: @LP Thanks for the feedback. The device will have network connectivity (TCP/IP), and the rootfs images will be around 50-100 MB. The end user is not very experienced with the low-level technical details like bootloaders, but he'll be able to build a new image version and now need a safe way to deploy it.