# Robust software update solutions for an OpenEmbedded/Yocto based system

Tags: yocto, openembedded

We are using a [Variscite VAR-SOM-AM33](http://www.variscite.com/products/system-on-module-som/cortex-a8/var-som-am33-cpu-ti-am335x-am3354-am3352) platform for our project, and software platform is based on [OpenEmbedded/Yocto](http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=VAR-SOM-AM33).

To ensure the hardware is running with the current software, the devices are connected to the internet. So far, we have been following the OE recipes and generating ipk and applying software updates via opkg.

However, the process is not satisfactory as some of the recipes are poorly written (fails to uninstall/install during the upgrade process). What **robust** technique/solution are available for OE/Yocto based systems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In additional to swupd suggested, has anyone have any experience with https://mender.io/?

Comment: Also found https://resin.io/ today. However it seems to require a custom resinOS. Anyone with experience with it?

Comment: Also found this whitepaper comparing various update solutions written for Automotive Grade Linux: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/automotive-discussions/2016-May/002061.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working on a metadata layer to integrate the Software Updater (swupd) from Clear Linux with the Yocto Project / OpenEmbedded Core.

swupd performs whole of OS updates, rather than package-based updates, using binary deltas to only update the files which change and to do so in an efficient manner.

I recently wrote some documentation (within the docs/Guide.md file in the meta-swupd repo) about adopting the "Clear Linux Way" to utilise meta-swupd from an OE/YP based distro. A wikified version of that guide, including a link to the layer git repository, are available on the Yocto Project wiki:
https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Meta-swupd

I also have a sample layer on Github which demonstrates use of the layer (this is also the distro layer I test much of meta-swupd with):
https://github.com/incandescant/meta-myhouse

Comment: @joshuagi, thanks for suggesting swupd, I also came across https://mender.io/. Do you have any experience with it? How does it compare?

Comment: @Charles I'd never heard of mender.io before now. Based on your description below (thanks for that) I'd point out two advantages of swupd as a) it is open source b) it's fully controlled by the distro builder (this may be an advantage or disadvantage depending on your perspective). Fortunately once the swupd artefacts are generated the only infrastructure required is the ability to serve files via http.

Comment: @joshuagi Thanks for the feedback. swupd appears to be more mature than mender.io. I am going through the official documentation for swupd (which needs some work) and your wiki link. Will give it a try after I have a better understanding. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add [SWUpdate](https://github.com/sbabic/swupdate) to the list of packages that you should consider. It was recommended in a [2016 paper by the Konsulko Group](https://www.konsulko.com/portfolio-item/device-side-software-update-for-agl-paper/) for Automotive-Grade Linux. That paper mentions a few other options, and provides an analysis of the various tools, so it's probably worth a read. Quoting from the paper:

> It is our recommendation that the reference AGL software update strategy make use of SWUpdate in a dual copy configuration and integrate OSTree support. This allows recovery from a corrupt partition for the exception case, but also optimizes the common case where small, incremental updates can be quickly applied or rolled back as needed to [meet] OEM policy.

I don't completely agree with the paper. For example, they wrote off Mender.io because it lacks community support, but IMO the Automotive-Grade Linux group is influential enough to create popularity from scratch. Still, it's a good paper, and the fact that they settled on SWUpdate was interesting to me. I was already leaning toward it because the author, [sbabic](https://github.com/sbabic), is involved in U-Boot software development, and we use U-Boot to burn new images into our device.

At the moment I'm unsatisfied with all of the current options, but mostly because I want extra functionality. I'll probably settle on a custom system which incorporates one or more of the aforementioned packages. Unfortunately that's not the kind of definitive answer that SO prefers, but I hope that it was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

About mender.io,  I have recently talked to them regarding their open-source update.

Currently, they already have their client side developed, and is working on the server side. They use HTTP and JSON.  This is their [git](https://github.com/mendersoftware/meta-mender), it is only supporting Beaglebone and QEMU at the moment.

The way mender.io works is: they will have one persistence data and uboot.  and 2 rootfs (active and backup) to update.  So, when there is an update on the server, the users will be notified to pull it down.  Give a `mender -rootfs image` update command.  And if the upgrade is success, the user gives another `mender -commit` command.  If there is no `mender -commit`, the rootfs will be rolled back to the previous rootfs in the next reboot.  Mender currently only support update of kernel and rootfs.

The main role of `mender.io` is to ensure that the mass distributed image upgrade process is recoverable from errors.  In the Server side, mender.io developed a management server to the mass distributed devices using UUID.

Not to advertise but please try out [mender.io](https://github.com/mendersoftware/mender) and give feedback so that the software could be more mature.

[Mender Introduction pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LghUD26CTfeG5EM2ktdnBWTjQ/view)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can either use package based upgrades, like you do. In that case, you'll need to test and verify everything locally before you push any updates to the field. Obviously, you'll likely need to improve a number of recipes. (And I assume that you upstream those immprovements, right?)

The alternative is to use image-based upgrades. Either with full images, see for instance the discussion at [Stackoverflow: Embedded Linux mechanism for deloying firmware updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617372/embedded-linux-mechanism-for-deploying-firmware-updates/31627984#31627984) or [swupd](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-swupd)

Note: I got distracted while writing this answer, so look at the answer from joshuagi; he explains a lot more of swupd.

Comment: Thanks @Anders. Thanks for the SO link. Good discuss on the merits of the 2 approaches.

Answer (score 3):

I think they are two problems here. We (OpenEmbedded) do need to be careful that we do not break package based updates.

Also, there are image updates like swupd (mentioned above and swupdate, described at: https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/swupdate.html

Answer (score 1):

Posts here were done years ago. Now also [RAUC](https://github.com/rauc/rauc/blob/master/README.rst) seems to be promising alternative to mender.io

Answer (score 0):

[meta-updater](https://github.com/advancedtelematic/meta-updater) provides support for [OSTree](https://ostree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/introduction/)-based updates to OE systems.

OSTree is interesting because it provides a half-way house between full image updates (which are large and tricky to handle correctly) and package based updates (which are tricky to make robust).  It has a 'git-like' object representation of a root filesystem, and uses chroot and hard links to atomically switch between file system images.

(Disclosure: I'm a contributor to meta-updater)